# Paypal Express Instant Update, no callback for default preferred address

Tags: php

My Paypal express checkout is working fine (sandbox and live). The payment is fine. I need to get the shipping address for calculating shipping price and did that using callback successfully. But a problem, when user logs into paypal, their preferred shipping address is listed. Paypal is not doing callback for this address. It does the callback when new address is entered or address is changed. In that case the shipping charge is returning correct (so I guess there is no error in my callback script). But why it is not making the callback for the preferred address immediately? It takes the default flat shipping amount sent. I searched on the web but find no answer. I checked the paypal console via chrome and found "Uncaught ReferenceError: ShippingHandling is not defined". Am I missing something in my request or other please?

Comment: According to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/ you should get the shipping address via callback after the user logs in to PayPal.

Comment: thank you CBroe, trying the same. but only getting callback to work when some changes in shipping address is made and save button in paypal is clicked but not immediately after login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved actually. It was google chrome that was crazy. Its cache sucks. Wasted my whole day. Never thought paypal also suffers from browser cache.